# JQuery UI Autocomplete from Coffeescript

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, coffeescript

I'm trying to use Jquery UI's autocomplete and have the following code

```
$( '#searchbar' ).autocomplete
source: ( request, response ) ->
$.ajax({
url: "$$ apiUrl pt.casemanagement $$/case/search"
})
success: ( data ) ->
            response([
              { label: "Example", value: 'Testing'}
            ])
```

I'm basically just waiting for the success and injecting a random label and value into the response for testing purposes.  The bar is definitely sending the GET and getting a 200.  I can even see the values from the server, but for whatever reason it doesnt seem like anything is being populated in the searchbar.  I should be able (as far as I understand) to type 'E' and see 'Example' auto suggested, right?

Does this syntax seem wrong?

Comment: It seems that the success handler is not firing, although I'm checking the JSON returned by the server and it passes JSONLint.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is indeed wrong. The main issue with it is indentation. Blocks are defined with indentation in CoffeeScript, so you probably wanted something like this:

```
$( '#searchbar' ).autocomplete
  source: ( request, response ) ->
    $.ajax({
      url: "$$ apiUrl pt.casemanagement $$/case/search"
      success: ( data ) ->
        response([
          { label: "Example", value: 'Testing'}
        ])
    })
```

Also, you were closing the options object to the `$.ajax` call before finishing the literal object definition. I didn't change any other whitespace or syntax to make it clear what the indentation implies.

In CoffeeScript, you can omit parens for function calls with arguments and braces around objects (unless it's ambiguous or you need to bypass the default precedence rules), so your code would look cleaner like this:

```
$('#searchbar').autocomplete
  source: (request, response) ->
    $.ajax
      url: "$$ apiUrl pt.casemanagement $$/case/search"
      success: (data) ->
        response [
          label: 'Example'
          value: 'Testing'
        ]
```

If you need further details about why and how this works, let me know and I can go line-by-line over it.

---

**Sidenote:** you're not using the `request` parameter to get the autocomplete values from the server. That means you probably won't get the expected results from the server, since you're not sending it the search term.